# Multiple Location on Google Map API not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google MAP API to show multiple location on google map, I generated the key also but when i run this code it gives me error 
`uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: myMap is not a function`.

Have i done any thing in a wrong way. Any point why i am getting this error

Key in below code is taken from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_basic)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 

  <!-- <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"      type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myMap() {

    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    }




      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

and if i use this tutorial with my API_KEY it works but show for development version only.
https://github.com/taniarascia/googlemaps

Comment: You keep asking questions but almost never accept or up-vote any answer you get. Did you understand how this website works?

Answer (score 0):

You should move this line

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap" type="text/javascript"></script>`

after your `myMap` function. You could put it as the last element in the `<body></body>` tag.

**Or** you can leave it where it is, remove the `callback=myMap` from the API call and call it manually in your script.

Also there is a good chance that you cannot use this key. Don't use a key (you will get a map "for development purposes only") or create your own key in your developer console.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myMap() {

      var locations = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
      ];

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      var marker, i;

      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      }

    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=myMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was a quick downvote for a working solution. How does it "not work" for you? Let me update my answer with working code...

Comment: @MrUpsidedown, I didnt down vote even my question was downvoted also. Hate when people downvote without any details.. How can we then Improve if we dont see reason for downvote.. Appreciate anyone who atleast reply or try to help..

Comment: Never mind. See my updated answer. Moving that line where I said (and removing the key) fixed the issues.

Comment: I have generated my own Key even then i am getting Development purspose only. I will try you code again..

Comment: Ok but that is a different issue than the one you described in your original question. When did you generate that key? You should allow a few minutes for the key to be usable. Also did you create a billing account for that key, etc.?

Comment: I was using my Key in actual code, for this question i used the sample key from w3schools.com..

Comment: Sure, but the issue you described was `uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: myMap is not a function` which is fixed for me with the code I posted. Now if your key doesn't work, this is another issue. I suggest you read [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api-key-billing-errors) and ensure you have done everything correctly.

Comment: I have generated new key also i still keep getting for development purpose only..